# Button's text vertical align

Tags: html, css

I have got tricky problem here. I'd like to vertical align my text inside a button

```
<button id="rock" onClick="choose(1)">Rock</button>
```

And here is my CSS

```
button {
    font-size: 22px;
    border: 2px solid #87231C;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: #FF5A51;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
button:active {
    font-size: 22px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

You can check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/kA8pp/ . I want to have the text on the bottom. **Thank you very much!**

**EDIT:** I can't explain it well so here is the picture of it  :)

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by on the bottom, as in under the picture or just at the bottom of the picture?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try  `padding-top:65px;` in button class

```
button {
    font-size: 22px;
    border: 2px solid #87231C;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: #FF5A51;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    padding-top:65px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kA8pp/4/)

Answer (score 29):

You can use `line-height` to achieve your goal.

```
button {
    font-size: 22px;
    border: 2px solid #87231C;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: #FF5A51;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    line-height: 150px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kA8pp/2/

Comment: I will use padding-top:65px; as someone said it here. But thank you very much also. :)

Comment: +1, Was about to write the same answer. @MíraKapičiak, Padding is a wrong way to solve this. This is the correct way.

Comment: cool.  using line-height I can put text at bottom but how about vertically aligning it to the top?

Comment: I'm here because I'm trying *not* to use line-height, which renders differently across browsers on many fonts. Turns out its not so easy..

Answer (score 22):

You can use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) (check [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox), depending on your needs).

```
button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-end; 
}
```

Comment: yeah thanks this worked for me. the display part especially.

Comment: Seems to be the only really flexible way to affect vertical alignment in a button.

Comment: This is not reliable solution, as [buttons can't be flex elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464067/flexbox-not-working-on-button-or-fieldset-elements)

Answer (score 2):

**Buttons Style Differently: A Variation on Styling**

The `<button>` element behaves a bit differently from some other elements, say a `<div>`.  If you set `display: table-cell` in a button, it does not affect the layout, so `vertical-align` will allow you to control the text position.

On the other hand, one could do the following:

```
<div class="button" id="rock" onClick="choose(1)">Rock</div>
```

and use the following CSS:

```
.button {
    font-size: 22px;
    border: 2px solid #87231C;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    color: #FF5A51;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

In this case, you have some control by adjusting padding and height.

If you are binding a JavaScript action to the element, it does not really matter all that much what the tag is, div or button.

This approach may some advantages in particular situations.

If you apply the above CSS to a button tag, it will not work.  Good to know.

http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/QSap8/

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you!

```
<pre>
.button{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #444;
    width: 32px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</pre>
```