# How align center text in custom buttons?

Tags: html, css

I have this html

```
<head>
<title>HTML5 App</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/buttons.css"> 

</head>

<body>
<!--Estructura -->


<div id="botones">
    <button class="btn" data-am-type="button">Soy un &lt;button&gt;</button>
    <a class="btn" data-am-type="button">Soy un &lt;a&gt;</a>
    <div class="btn" data-am-type="button">Soy un &lt;div&gt;</div>
    <input class="btn" type="button" value="Soy un <input>">
</div>

</body>
```

In < button > and < input >, text is align center of the button but in < a > and < div >, text is shown top of the button. I think < button > and < input > inherit some property and so they align text in the middle of button.

I see this

[image: pic]

and i want that all buttons align text in the middle.

The class "btn" is this

```
.btn{
display: inline-block;
padding: 4px 12px; /* Padding por defecto */
font-size: 16px;  /* Tamaño fuente por defecto */
line-height: 20px; /* Tamaño de linea */
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;

font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

cursor: pointer;
height: 80px;
background-color: #f5f5f5; /* por si no se ve el gradiente, aunque si lo pruebo en Chrome nunca deberia verse este color*/
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#e6e6e6));

border: 1px solid #cccccc;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button's text vertical align](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487408/buttons-text-vertical-align)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To vertically-centre the text of these elements, simply set the `line-height` of the element's text equal to the `height` of the element, and set `box-sizing` to `border-box` (in order that the `height` of all elements are the same:

```
.btn {
    /* other, unchanged, CSS */
    line-height: 80px; /* <- changed this */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* <- added this */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ScET3/).

Obviously this does cause issues, should the text wrap to a second line.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the
`padding:4px 12px;` from the .btn class
and set the
`line-height:`
as per your requirement, then the text would come in the center of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I think create height with setting padding for `a` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
border: none;
outline: 0;
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration: none;
overflow: visible;
background: none;
padding:0 16px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
color: #222
```

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

it should be, simply: line-height: 0.25em;

Answer (score 0):

I use such approach:

```
.btn {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
 }
```

It useful when text in button has 2 raws. line-heigt will broke 2 raws

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex;` to make your work easier. Just look at the code below.

```css
#botones {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 5px;
}
.btn{
  padding: 4px 12px; /* Padding por defecto */
  font-size: 16px;  /* Tamaño fuente por defecto */
  line-height: 20px; /* Tamaño de linea */
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;

  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

  cursor: pointer;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5; /* por si no se ve el gradiente, aunque si lo pruebo en Chrome nunca deberia verse este color*/
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#e6e6e6));

  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}
#botones a,
#botones div {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
<title>HTML5 App</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/buttons.css"> 

</head>

<body>
<!--Estructura -->


<div id="botones">
    <button class="btn" data-am-type="button">Soy un &lt;button&gt;</button>
    <a class="btn" data-am-type="button">Soy un &lt;a&gt;</a>
    <div class="btn" data-am-type="button">Soy un &lt;div&gt;</div>
    <input class="btn" type="button" value="Soy un <input>">
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a `display:table-cell;` for the .btn class.

like

```
.btn{display:table-cell;}
```

This will create the vertical alignment for the `Div` as well as `a` elements having the class .btn.
Hope this helps.

Comment: IE7 or lower? The tag button itself is not supported for IE7 or lower. Probably you forgot to mention that. Right? - @chalist

Comment: You also ignored an important point of the snippet. i.e the title tag. It has mentioned <title>HTML5 App</title>. HTML5. You can write to the user who has asked this and say that it is "not supported in IE7 or lower". Right? - @chalist

Answer (score -1):

Remove this : `height: 80px;`

Your padding : `padding: 4px 12px;`

After you remove the height padding must be ~ `padding: 30px 12px;`

You must set the padding fine (based on your text height).

Answer (score -3):

```
vertical-align:center;
```

use that and it will work