# Bars in burger menu buttons are vertically centered without CSS

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu

I'm making a CSS based burger menu button, and I noticed that the `<span>` bars are **vertically centered** by default. Inspecting and playing around with **the bars'** margin keeps the elements **vertically centered**.

But if I try the same code and replace the `<button>` with a `<div>`, it's no more vertically aligned.

```css
.toggle-btn {
  display: block;
  background: #eee;
  border: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px auto 30px;
}
.toggle-btn .bar {
  display: block;
  background: #000;
  width: 24px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.toggle-btn .bar + .bar {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>this is a button</p>
<button class="toggle-btn">
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
</button>

<p>this is a div</p>
<div class="toggle-btn">
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
</div>
```

This is completely new to me, and there doesn't seem to be any browser default CSS that seems to cause this. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

I'm curious on how this happens. What causes the bars inside a `<button>` to be vertically centered?

Comment: If you would change the height from `.toggle-btn` to `140px` it would make your question even more obvious.

Comment: actually `margin:0 auto` keeps the `.bar` centered horizontally not vertically...

Comment: hope that my answer resolved your problem

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code does the trick

```
.toggle-btn .bar + .bar {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

It adds a `margin-top` to the second and third bar.

Comment: but removing `margin-top` altogether still keeps the bars vertically centered. My question is, what is keeping them vertically centered?

Comment: Its because the `<span>`s are no more an `inline` element but a `block` element. `.toggle-btn .bar{display: block}`. And they, by default, stacks one below another.

Comment: @DriftingSteps centered using this `.toggle-btn{margin:50px auto;}`

Comment: I don't think you understand what my question is. I'm talking about the black bars. Why are the black bars vertically centered inside the button? What is causing that?

Comment: Its because your parent element is a `<button>` which by default center its contents. Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667536/how-align-center-text-in-custom-buttons and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160270/vertically-align-contents-of-a-button-other-than-center if you need to change the alignment.

Answer (score 0):

that is the default property of `<button>` element.if you write any content inside html `<button>` tag ,that will appear vertically centered.I'm added one example below.

```css
.button-element{
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 border:1px solid #000;
 background-color:yellow;
}

.button-child{
width:100px;
border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<button class="button-element">
  <span class="button-child"></div>
</button>
```

Comment: `div` inside `button`...really...?

Comment: I see that it's a default property. But does the browser implement this default property feature without browser CSS?

Comment: @bhuwan  div or span,anything will result in same

Comment: @DreamHunter Element `div` not allowed as child of element `button` in this context...its not valid

Comment: @Bhuwan ok i'm edited,i"m just tried to show that the vertical alignment is a default property of <button> tag.it didn't depends on whatever content inside.

Answer (score -2):

By default the bootstrap keeps the hamburger menu vertically.
So,

`.toggle-bar{
float:"top";
}`

```
float:top **might help fix this.**
```

Comment: `float: top;` ? [doesn't exist !](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

Comment: What @caramba said. Also, that's not my question.