# How can i turn off automatic vertical alignment of <button>'s contents?

Tags: html, css, webkit

Is there a way to turn this feature off? Contents of `<button>` are always vertically centered, as opposed to what happens in a regular HTML tag.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HbqnR/

I want `<button>` behave like `<a>`, with the text at the top left corner of the button.

**I'm looking for a WebKit specific fix**, maybe there is some `-webkit-*` css property that controls this behavior. **Hacks are welcome but without using additional markup!**

Thank you in advance :)

---

```
.button
{
    display:inline-block;
    height:200px;
    border:4px gainsboro outset;
    background:silver;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:200px;
    text-align:left;
}

<button class="button">&lt;button&gt;</button>
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="button">&lt;a&gt;</a>
```

Comment: i don't think we can turn off that

Comment: <input type="button" class="button" value="&lt;button&gt;" /> also same.We can try javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Button's text vertical align](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487408/buttons-text-vertical-align)

Comment: I think, to specifically answer your question, no - you cannot turn it off. No CSS rule can target the content of a button, other than to add content to it via `:before` and/or `:after`. You would have to target it via an additional element, as others here have shown, or via Javascript (which would just do the same).

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

```
button:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    margin-top:-50%;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/r6yXw/

And, if you want it to only apply to webkit based browsers, wrap it in

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { ... }
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/r6yXw/1/

Answer (score 0):

I see that you requested no additional markup, but if you decide to go down that route, one quick idea is to use positioning and one additional element.

```
button {
  position: relative;
}

button > span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

<button><span>&lt;button&gt;</span></button>
```

Comment: yes I've considered this solution but I'm looking for something that doesn't force me to use additional markup, thanks anyway! :)

Comment: This prevents the contents from growing vertically

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Not without introducing a `<span>` inside the `<button>` and use positioning:

```
<button class="button"><span>&lt;button&gt;</span></button>
```

Then add the following to `.button`:

```
.button
{
    /* ... */
    position:relative;
}

.button > span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HbqnR/6/)

If you want to keep your HTML intact, you can modify the document using JavaScript as well:

```
$('button.button').wrapInner('<span>');
```

Note that if JavaScript is disabled, it won't work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
button {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this out :P [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HbqnR/5/)

```
   .button
{
    display:block;
    height:200px;
    border:4px gainsboro outset;
    background:silver;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:200px;
    text-align:left;
    text-indent: 0;
    white-space: normal;
    word-spacing: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    float: left;
    top:0;
}
```

It might work heh. I don't really know what do you need the button for. But this gets to see just like what you were asking before.
Used it here.

```
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <button class="button">tODAY WE ARE HERE WONDERING WHAT TO DO<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p></button>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: This is just adding a bunch of empty paragraphs to enforce the total size of text to grow and thus pulling the first line up.