# How exactly is a <button> rendered by a browser?

Tags: css, button, anchor, vertical-alignment

Why does `<button>` always have its text vertically aligned but not.. Say, an anchor tag that is using the **same styles**?

**Same styles** meaning both have same display, padding, line height, text-align and vertical-align. But as soon as I change the tag from `<button>` to `<a>`, it breaks, text is no longer vertically-aligned

This is tough to figure out. I even went to check the webkit-core to find answers. I checked what does the `<button>` element has and copied it out.
http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css

This guy says `<button>` is styled differently but how?
[Button's text vertical align](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487408/buttons-text-vertical-align)

Can someone tell me how exactly is a `<button>` is rendered by a browser?

Comment: I think this is to complicate to anwser because you don't know how a browser was coded. So you have to live with the webkit documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Were you going for something like this?

**HTML**

```
<button>...</button>
<br>
<a>...</a>
```

**CSS**

```
button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}
a {
    padding: 2px 8px;
    -webkit-appearance: button; 
}
```

Link to fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/846d4m8o/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I said **text is no longer vertically-aligned**. Not the looks, because I have `-webkit-appearance: button` on my code as well.

Comment: @ Duane-Adam I'm not sure if I really understand what you are asking.